# Css animation prevent jump to first frame

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to implement infinite rotation for this indicator. how do I prevent the animation from jumping back to first `45deg` frame?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
}

#indicator {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#indicator:before {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #0095ff;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: rotate 4s infinite;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#indicator:after {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  content: "Title";
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="indicator"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove the last state and re-adjust the % of each one as needed. When the transformation will end with `315deg` it will get back immediately to `45deg` which is equivalent to `315deg` then the animation will start again and it will always run in the same direction.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
}

#js-waiting-indicator {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#js-waiting-indicator:before {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #0095ff;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: rotate 4s infinite;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#js-waiting-indicator:after {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  content: "Title";
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="js-waiting-indicator"></div>
```